# Copy docker configuration to other PC

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I’m using docker composer in order to run ChirpStack on my Windows 10 machine. I need to reinstall operating system, but how to keep working ChirpStack docker system without creating new one?

Comment: Are you asking if you can have docker running while you reinstall the Windows 10 OS ?
Or are you asking if you can move your docker containers to the reinstalled Windows 10 machine? You need to look over your question because as it is now its not clear at all!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Once you remove the existing OS docker will no longer be able to communicate with the kernel. Even if you reinstall the OS it would not be the same. You will have to remove docker and install it again. Unless you are using persistent volumes, the docker container data will also get erased. You can check this by having a snapshot or a recovery point before reinstalling the OS.